# Duplicating a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, duplicates

Okay, sorry if this is a really basic one but I've been doing a piece of software for a ten pin bowling score system, finally got all the functionality for the score system working however this is only for one player, I am trying to duplicate the function to give a function per player (up to six players) As I say part of the code is there but when I tried duplicating the function and renaming the variables  etc it breaks the code, any help would be appreciated!

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Bowling Score Calculator</title>
    <script>
    onebowl = new Array(21);
    twobowl = new Array(21);
    threebowl = new Array(21);
    fourbowl = new Array(21);
    fivebowl = new Array(21);
    sixbowl = new Array(21);
    score = new Array(11);
    scoretwo = new Array(11);
    scorethree = new Array(11);
    scorefour = new Array(11);
    scorefive = new Array(11);
    scoresix = new Array(11);

    function runScript() {
    store();
    valid = verify();
    if(valid) {calculate();calculatetwo();print();}}

    function store(){
    onebowl[0]=document.score.pl1bowl1.value;
    onebowl[1]=document.score.pl1bowl2.value;
    onebowl[2]=document.score.pl1bowl3.value;
    onebowl[3]=document.score.pl1bowl4.value;
    onebowl[4]=document.score.pl1bowl5.value;
    onebowl[5]=document.score.pl1bowl6.value;
    onebowl[6]=document.score.pl1bowl7.value;
    onebowl[7]=document.score.pl1bowl8.value;
    onebowl[8]=document.score.pl1bowl9.value;
    onebowl[9]=document.score.pl1bowl10.value;
    onebowl[10]=document.score.pl1bowl11.value;
    onebowl[11]=document.score.pl1bowl12.value;
    onebowl[12]=document.score.pl1bowl13.value;
    onebowl[13]=document.score.pl1bowl14.value;
    onebowl[14]=document.score.pl1bowl15.value;
    onebowl[15]=document.score.pl1bowl16.value;
    onebowl[16]=document.score.pl1bowl17.value;
    onebowl[17]=document.score.pl1bowl18.value;
    onebowl[18]=document.score.pl1bowl19.value;
    onebowl[19]=document.score.pl1bowl20.value;
    onebowl[20]=document.score.pl1bowl21.value;

    twobowl[0]=document.score.pl2bowl1.value;
    twobowl[1]=document.score.pl2bowl2.value;
    twobowl[2]=document.score.pl2bowl3.value;
twobowl[3]=document.score.pl2bowl4.value;
twobowl[4]=document.score.pl2bowl5.value;
twobowl[5]=document.score.pl2bowl6.value;
twobowl[6]=document.score.pl2bowl7.value;
twobowl[7]=document.score.pl2bowl8.value;
twobowl[8]=document.score.pl2bowl9.value;
twobowl[9]=document.score.pl2bowl10.value;
twobowl[10]=document.score.pl2bowl11.value;
twobowl[11]=document.score.pl2bowl12.value;
twobowl[12]=document.score.pl2bowl13.value;
twobowl[13]=document.score.pl2bowl14.value;
twobowl[14]=document.score.pl2bowl15.value;
twobowl[15]=document.score.pl2bowl16.value;
twobowl[16]=document.score.pl2bowl17.value;
twobowl[17]=document.score.pl2bowl18.value;
twobowl[18]=document.score.pl2bowl19.value;
twobowl[19]=document.score.pl2bowl20.value;
twobowl[20]=document.score.pl2bowl21.value;

threebowl[0]=document.score.pl3bowl1.value;
threebowl[1]=document.score.pl3bowl2.value;
threebowl[2]=document.score.pl3bowl3.value;
threebowl[3]=document.score.pl3bowl4.value;
threebowl[4]=document.score.pl3bowl5.value;
threebowl[5]=document.score.pl3bowl6.value;
threebowl[6]=document.score.pl3bowl7.value;
threebowl[7]=document.score.pl3bowl8.value;
threebowl[8]=document.score.pl3bowl9.value;
threebowl[9]=document.score.pl3bowl10.value;
threebowl[10]=document.score.pl3bowl11.value;
threebowl[11]=document.score.pl3bowl12.value;
threebowl[12]=document.score.pl3bowl13.value;
threebowl[13]=document.score.pl3bowl14.value;
threebowl[14]=document.score.pl3bowl15.value;
threebowl[15]=document.score.pl3bowl16.value;
threebowl[16]=document.score.pl3bowl17.value;
threebowl[17]=document.score.pl3bowl18.value;
threebowl[18]=document.score.pl3bowl19.value;
threebowl[19]=document.score.pl3bowl20.value;
threebowl[20]=document.score.pl3bowl21.value;

fourbowl[0]=document.score.pl4bowl1.value;
fourbowl[1]=document.score.pl4bowl2.value;
fourbowl[2]=document.score.pl4bowl3.value;
fourbowl[3]=document.score.pl4bowl4.value;
fourbowl[4]=document.score.pl4bowl5.value;
fourbowl[5]=document.score.pl4bowl6.value;
fourbowl[6]=document.score.pl4bowl7.value;
fourbowl[7]=document.score.pl4bowl8.value;
fourbowl[8]=document.score.pl4bowl9.value;
fourbowl[9]=document.score.pl4bowl10.value;
fourbowl[10]=document.score.pl4bowl11.value;
fourbowl[11]=document.score.pl4bowl12.value;
fourbowl[12]=document.score.pl4bowl13.value;
fourbowl[13]=document.score.pl4bowl14.value;
fourbowl[14]=document.score.pl4bowl15.value;
fourbowl[15]=document.score.pl4bowl16.value;
fourbowl[16]=document.score.pl4bowl17.value;
fourbowl[17]=document.score.pl4bowl18.value;
fourbowl[18]=document.score.pl4bowl19.value;
fourbowl[19]=document.score.pl4bowl20.value;
fourbowl[20]=document.score.pl4bowl21.value;

fivebowl[0]=document.score.pl5bowl1.value;
fivebowl[1]=document.score.pl5bowl2.value;
fivebowl[2]=document.score.pl5bowl3.value;
fivebowl[3]=document.score.pl5bowl4.value;
fivebowl[4]=document.score.pl5bowl5.value;
fivebowl[5]=document.score.pl5bowl6.value;
fivebowl[6]=document.score.pl5bowl7.value;
fivebowl[7]=document.score.pl5bowl8.value;
fivebowl[8]=document.score.pl5bowl9.value;
fivebowl[9]=document.score.pl5bowl10.value;
fivebowl[10]=document.score.pl5bowl11.value;
fivebowl[11]=document.score.pl5bowl12.value;
fivebowl[12]=document.score.pl5bowl13.value;
fivebowl[13]=document.score.pl5bowl14.value;
fivebowl[14]=document.score.pl5bowl15.value;
fivebowl[15]=document.score.pl5bowl16.value;
fivebowl[16]=document.score.pl5bowl17.value;
fivebowl[17]=document.score.pl5bowl18.value;
fivebowl[18]=document.score.pl5bowl19.value;
fivebowl[19]=document.score.pl5bowl20.value;
fivebowl[20]=document.score.pl5bowl21.value;

sixbowl[0]=document.score.pl6bowl1.value;
sixbowl[1]=document.score.pl6bowl2.value;
sixbowl[2]=document.score.pl6bowl3.value;
sixbowl[3]=document.score.pl6bowl4.value;
sixbowl[4]=document.score.pl6bowl5.value;
sixbowl[5]=document.score.pl6bowl6.value;
sixbowl[6]=document.score.pl6bowl7.value;
sixbowl[7]=document.score.pl6bowl8.value;
sixbowl[8]=document.score.pl6bowl9.value;
sixbowl[9]=document.score.pl6bowl10.value;
sixbowl[10]=document.score.pl6bowl11.value;
sixbowl[11]=document.score.pl6bowl12.value;
sixbowl[12]=document.score.pl6bowl13.value;
sixbowl[13]=document.score.pl6bowl14.value;
sixbowl[14]=document.score.pl6bowl15.value;
sixbowl[15]=document.score.pl6bowl16.value;
sixbowl[16]=document.score.pl6bowl17.value;
sixbowl[17]=document.score.pl6bowl18.value;
sixbowl[18]=document.score.pl6bowl19.value;
sixbowl[19]=document.score.pl6bowl20.value;
sixbowl[20]=document.score.pl6bowl21.value;
}

function verify(){
//for first 9 frames
for(i=0;i<=17;i+=2){
switch(onebowl[i]){//first bowl of frame
case 'x':case '0':case '1':case '2':case '3':case '4':case '5':case '6':case '7':case '8':case '9':break;
default: alert("Please enter a valid number! Make sure the total for each frame is not above 9, if a spare is scored please enter '/'");return false;}

switch(onebowl[i+1]){//second bowl of frame
case '/': if(onebowl[i] < '0' || onebowl[i] > '9'){alert("Invalid");return false;}
case '0':case '1':case '2':case '3':case '4':case '5':case '6':case '7':case '8':case '9': if(parseInt(onebowl[i]) + parseInt(onebowl[i+1]) >9){alert("Invalid");return false;}break;
default: if(onebowl[i] != 'x'){alert("Invalid");return false;}}
}

//for tenth frame
switch(onebowl[18]){//first bowl
case 'x':case '0':case '1':case '2':case '3':case '4':case '5':case '6':case '7':case '8':case '9':break;
default: alert("Invalid");return false;}

switch(onebowl[19]){//second bowl
case 'x':if(onebowl[18] != 'x'){alert("Invalid");return false;}break;
case '/':if(onebowl[18] < '0' || onebowl[18] > '9'){alert("Invalid");return false;}break;
case '0':case'1':case'2':case'3':case'4':case'5':case'6':case'7':case'8':case'9':
if(onebowl[18] != 'x'){if(parseInt(onebowl[18])+parseInt(onebowl[19])>9){alert("Invalid");return false;}}break;
default:alert("Invalid");return false;}

if(onebowl[18] != 'x' && onebowl[19] != '/')return true;

switch(onebowl[20]){//third bowl
case 'x':if(onebowl[19] != 'x' && onebowl[19] != '/'){alert("Invalid");return false;}break;
case '/':if(onebowl[19] < '0' || onebowl[19] > '9'){alert("Invalid");return false;}break;
case '0':case'1':case'2':case'3':case'4':case'5':case'6':case'7':case'8':case'9':
if(onebowl[19] != 'x' && onebowl[19] != '/'){if(parseInt(onebowl[18])+parseInt(onebowl[19])>9){alert("Invalid");return false;}}break;
default:alert("Invalid");return false;}

return true;}

function calculate(){
frame = 0;
lastFrame = 0;
for(i=0;i<8;i++){//first 8 frames
if (onebowl[2*i] == 'x'){//strike this frame
    if ((onebowl[2*i+2] == 'x') && (onebowl[2*i+4] == 'x')) //strike on next 2 bowls
        score[i] = lastFrame + 30;
    else if (onebowl[2*i+2] == 'x') //one more strike after this
        score[i] = lastFrame + 20 + parseInt(onebowl[2*i+4]);
    else if (onebowl[2*i+3] == '/') //strike followed by a spare
        score[i] = lastFrame + 20;
    else //strike followed by an open
        score[i] = lastFrame + 10 + parseInt(onebowl[2*i+2]) + parseInt(onebowl[2*i+3]);}

else if (onebowl[2*i+1] == '/'){ //spare this frame
    if (onebowl[2*i+2] == 'x') //next bowl is a strike
        score[i] = lastFrame + 20;
    else //next bowl not a strike
        score[i] = lastFrame + 10 + parseInt(onebowl[2*i+2]);}

else //open this frame
    score[i] = lastFrame + parseInt(onebowl[2*i])+parseInt(onebowl[2*i+1]);
lastFrame = score[i];
}
//9th frame
if (onebowl[16] == 'x'){//strike this frame
    if ((onebowl[18] == 'x') && (onebowl[19] == 'x'))//followed by 2 strikes in tenth
        score[8] = lastFrame + 30;
    else if (onebowl[18] == 'x')//followed by 1 strike in the tenth
        score[8] = lastFrame + 20 + parseInt(onebowl[19]);
    else if (onebowl[19] == '/')//followed by a spare in the tenth
        score[8] = lastFrame + 20;
    else//followed by an open in the tenth
        score[8] = lastFrame + 10 + parseInt(onebowl[18])+parseInt(onebowl[19]);}

else if (onebowl[17] == '/'){//spare this frame
    if (onebowl[18] == 'x')//followed by a strike in tenth
        score[8] = lastFrame + 20;
    else//followed by something else
        score[8] = lastFrame + 10 + parseInt(onebowl[18]);}

else //open this frame
    score[8] = lastFrame + parseInt(onebowl[16]) + parseInt(onebowl[17]);
lastFrame = score[8];
//10th frame
if (onebowl[18] == 'x'){ //first bowl is a strike
    if ((onebowl[19] == 'x') && (onebowl[20] == 'x'))//3 strikes in the tenth
        score[9] = lastFrame + 30;
    else if (onebowl[19] == 'x')//first 2 are strikes
        score[9] = lastFrame + 20 + parseInt(onebowl[20]);
    else if (bowl[20] == '/')//one strike followed by a spare
        score[9] = lastFrame + 20;
    else//one strike followed by an open
        score[9] = lastFrame + 10 + parseInt(onebowl[19]) + parseInt(onebowl[20]);}

else if (onebowl[19] == '/'){ //first bowl is a spare
    if (onebowl[20] == 'x') //spare followed by a strike
        score[9] = lastFrame + 20;
    else//spare followed by an open
        score[9] = lastFrame + 10 + parseInt(onebowl[20]);}

else //open in the tenth
    score[9] = lastFrame + parseInt(onebowl[18]) + parseInt(onebowl[19]);
}


function print(){
player1score1.innerHTML ="";
player1score1.innerHTML += "" + score[0];
player1score2.innerHTML ="";
player1score2.innerHTML += "" + score[1];
player1score3.innerHTML ="";
player1score3.innerHTML += "" + score[2];
player1score4.innerHTML ="";
player1score4.innerHTML += "" + score[3];
player1score5.innerHTML ="";
player1score5.innerHTML += "" + score[4];
player1score6.innerHTML ="";
player1score6.innerHTML += "" + score[5];
player1score7.innerHTML ="";
player1score7.innerHTML += "" + score[6];
player1score8.innerHTML ="";
player1score8.innerHTML += "" + score[7];
player1score9.innerHTML ="";
player1score9.innerHTML += "" + score[8];
player1score10.innerHTML ="";
player1score10.innerHTML += "" + score[9];
player2score1.innerHTML ="";
player2score1.innerHTML += "" + scoretwo[0];
player2score2.innerHTML ="";
player2score2.innerHTML += "" + scoretwo[1];
player2score3.innerHTML ="";
player2score3.innerHTML += "" + scoretwo[2];
player2score4.innerHTML ="";
player2score4.innerHTML += "" + scoretwo[3];
player2score5.innerHTML ="";
player2score5.innerHTML += "" + scoretwo[4];
player2score6.innerHTML ="";
player2score6.innerHTML += "" + scoretwo[5];
player2score7.innerHTML ="";
player2score7.innerHTML += "" + scoretwo[6];
player2score8.innerHTML ="";
player2score8.innerHTML += "" + scoretwo[7];
player2score9.innerHTML ="";
player2score9.innerHTML += "" + scoretwo[8];
player2score10.innerHTML ="";
player2score10.innerHTML += "" + scoretwo[9];   
player3score1.innerHTML ="";
player3score1.innerHTML += "" + scorethree[0];
player3score2.innerHTML ="";
player3score2.innerHTML += "" + scorethree[1];
player3score3.innerHTML ="";
player3score3.innerHTML += "" + scorethree[2];
player3score4.innerHTML ="";
player3score4.innerHTML += "" + scorethree[3];
player3score5.innerHTML ="";
player3score5.innerHTML += "" + scorethree[4];
player3score6.innerHTML ="";
player3score6.innerHTML += "" + scorethree[5];
player3score7.innerHTML ="";
player3score7.innerHTML += "" + scorethree[6];
player3score8.innerHTML ="";
player3score8.innerHTML += "" + scorethree[7];
player3score9.innerHTML ="";
player3score9.innerHTML += "" + scorethree[8];
player3score10.innerHTML ="";
player3score10.innerHTML += "" + scorethree[9];   
player4score1.innerHTML ="";
player4score1.innerHTML += "" + scorefour[0];
player4score2.innerHTML ="";
player4score2.innerHTML += "" + scorefour[1];
player4score3.innerHTML ="";
player4score3.innerHTML += "" + scorefour[2];
player4score4.innerHTML ="";
player4score4.innerHTML += "" + scorefour[3];
player4score5.innerHTML ="";
player4score5.innerHTML += "" + scorefour[4];
player4score6.innerHTML ="";
player4score6.innerHTML += "" + scorefour[5];
player4score7.innerHTML ="";
player4score7.innerHTML += "" + scorefour[6];
player4score8.innerHTML ="";
player4score8.innerHTML += "" + scorefour[7];
player4score9.innerHTML ="";
player4score9.innerHTML += "" + scorefour[8];
player4score10.innerHTML ="";
player4score10.innerHTML += "" + scorefour[9];   
player5score1.innerHTML ="";
player5score1.innerHTML += "" + scorefive[0];
player5score2.innerHTML ="";
player5score2.innerHTML += "" + scorefive[1];
player5score3.innerHTML ="";
player5score3.innerHTML += "" + scorefive[2];
player5score4.innerHTML ="";
player5score4.innerHTML += "" + scorefive[3];
player5score5.innerHTML ="";
player5score5.innerHTML += "" + scorefive[4];
player5score6.innerHTML ="";
player5score6.innerHTML += "" + scorefive[5];
player5score7.innerHTML ="";
player5score7.innerHTML += "" + scorefive[6];
player5score8.innerHTML ="";
player5score8.innerHTML += "" + scorefive[7];
player5score9.innerHTML ="";
player5score9.innerHTML += "" + scorefive[8];
player5score10.innerHTML ="";
player5score10.innerHTML += "" + scorefive[9];
player6score1.innerHTML ="";
player6score1.innerHTML += "" + scoresix[0];
player6score2.innerHTML ="";
player6score2.innerHTML += "" + scoresix[1];
player6score3.innerHTML ="";
player6score3.innerHTML += "" + scoresix[2];
player6score4.innerHTML ="";
player6score4.innerHTML += "" + scoresix[3];
player6score5.innerHTML ="";
player6score5.innerHTML += "" + scoresix[4];
player6score6.innerHTML ="";
player6score6.innerHTML += "" + scoresix[5];
player6score7.innerHTML ="";
player6score7.innerHTML += "" + scoresix[6];
player6score8.innerHTML ="";
player6score8.innerHTML += "" + scoresix[7];
player6score9.innerHTML ="";
player6score9.innerHTML += "" + scoresix[8];
player6score10.innerHTML ="";
player6score10.innerHTML += "" + scoresix[9];   
}

</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <center><img src="http://www.dr-designs.co.uk/bowlarama.png"></center>

<form name="score">
&nbsp;<center>
<table border="0"  cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="AutoNumber1" height="45">
  <tr>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent"><font color="#000000"><b>Frame</b></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent" align="center"><font color="#000000"><b>1</b></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent" align="center"><font color="#000000"><b>2</b></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent" align="center"><font color="#000000"><b>3</b></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent" align="center"><font color="#000000"><b>4</b></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent" align="center"><font color="#000000"><b>5</b></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent" align="center"><font color="#000000"><b>6</b></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent" align="center"><font color="#000000"><b>7</b></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent" align="center"><font color="#000000"><b>8</b></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent" align="center"><font color="#000000"><b>9</b></font></td>
    <td width="7%" height="19" bgcolor="transparent" align="center"><font color="#000000"><b>10</b></font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><!--This is the form for the 1st player-->
    <td id="player1name" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent"><font color="#000000"><b>Score</b></font></td>
    <td id="player1score1" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl1">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl2">
    </td>
    <td id="player1score2" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl3"> 
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl4">
    </td>
    <td id="player1score3" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl5">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl6">
    </td>
    <td id="player1score4" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl7">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl8">
    </td>
    <td id="player1score5" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl9">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl10">
    </td>
    <td id="player1score6" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl11">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl12">
    </td>
    <td id="player1score7" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl13">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl14">
    </td>
    <td id="player1score8" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl15">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl16">
    </td>
    <td id="player1score9" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl17">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl18">
    </td>
    <td id="player1score10" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl19">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl20">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl1bowl21">
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr><!--This is the form for the 2nd player-->
    <td id="player2name" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent"><font color="#000000"><b>Score</b></font></td>
    <td id="player2score1" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl1">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl2">
    </td>
    <td id="player2score2" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl3"> 
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl4">
    </td>
    <td id="player2score3" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl5">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl6">
    </td>
    <td id="player2score4" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl7">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl8">
    </td>
    <td id="player2score5" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl9">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl10">
    </td>
    <td id="player2score6" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl11">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl12">
    </td>
    <td id="player2score7" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl13">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl14">
    </td>
    <td id="player2score8" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl15">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl16">
    </td>
    <td id="player2score9" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl17">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl18">
    </td>
    <td id="player2score10" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl19">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl20">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl2bowl21">
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr><!--This is the form for the 3rd player-->
    <td id="player3name" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent"><font color="#000000"><b>Score</b></font></td>
    <td id="player3score1" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl1">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl2">
    </td>
    <td id="player3score2" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl3">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl4">
    </td>
    <td id="player3score3" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl5">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl6">
    </td>
    <td id="player3score4" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl7">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl8">
    </td>
    <td id="player3score5" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl9">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl10">
    </td>
    <td id="player3score6" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl11">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl12">
    </td>
    <td id="player3score7" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl13">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl14">
    </td>
    <td id="player3score8" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl15">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl16">
    </td>
    <td id="player3score9" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl17">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl18">
    </td>
    <td id="player3score10" width="7%" height="16" bgcolor="transparent" align="center">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl19">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl20">
        <input type=text maxlength=1 size=1 name="pl3bowl21">
    </td>
  </tr>



</table>
<p><input type=button value="Calculate Score" onclick="runScript();">

    </center>
    </form>
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Had to remove the code for the form for the 4th, 5th and 6th player however these are the same as the previous ones(the variables are in the same format etc) Also i know it may not be the best code, this is my first attempt ever at javascript so I'm learning as I go along and I just need something I understand and can explain how it works to a panel for an assessment!

Comment: Also just realised I haven't explained what the software does, the players input their scores then when they press the submit button it calculates the scores and displays them to the plaers in the same boxes they entered their scores in

Comment: Computers are great at performing mundane, repetitive tasks. Programming languages have facility to tell the computer to do something repetitive. If you ever find yourself repeating something identical or very similar, you're doing the work that the computer should be doing.

Comment: we don't have a crystal ball.  "breaks the code" is not an adequate description of the problem.  What errors are you receiving?  what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors, before trying to get the other players functions working, when you pressed the submit button the calculate function worked out the score and displayed the scores in the existing table, replacing the input data.  When I try and introduce the code to give the same functionality to the other players the button no longer does anything when clicked.

Comment: Do you know where to look for the errors?

Comment: ...you didn't write the original code, did you.

Comment: I assumed you meant in dreamweaver showing syntax errors etc, how do I  look for the errors? Yes I did, I had help from a friend with it (hence why it's of a way higher standard)

Comment: Okay so I managed to get this working, using the evil that is copy and pasting my own code (turns out I'd missed out one of the pervious variables, thus breaking it!

Comment: Browsers have built-in developer tools. Find them and open them up, and you'll see that there's a console. Errors and other messages are reported there. You can log to the console with `console.log("my message")`, as well as other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the concept that

**Copying and Pasting Code is the Root of all EVIL**

My answer is, go back to the way you had it working for 1 user, and refactor so you can **reuse** that code in a generic way.  You can post your solution for 1 player to get design advice.

Even if you can get it working like this, you don't want to.  This is never ok.

Comment: Surely if its the exact same workings then it makes sense to copy the code that you already have perfected? It works perfectly well for one player i just need the same functionality for the other 5, surely isn't 'reusing' the code the same as copying and pasting it then changing the variables?

Comment: good god...NO.  Do you think that google copies and pastes code for each one of their millions of users?

Comment: I'm far from Google, as mentioned this is the first time I've coded in javascript, was just looking for a pointer towards a simple solution to make it functional, doesn't have to be pretty or be the 'right' way just functional

Comment: @Danny: hvgotcodes gave you the best  pointer you could hope to receive. No one will tell you to take this copy/paste/modify approach. You've got a `for` loop in your `calculate()` function that iterates `8` times. You could have done a copy/paste 8 times instead, but a loop made more sense. Apply the same to the rest of your code

Comment: *doesn't have to be pretty or be the 'right' way* It is not really about "pretty", so much as writing maintainable code you will still understand a month from now. Most people would tell you that debugging or modifying copy/paste/repeat code always takes longer than with generic code. That is basically wasted time that could be spent on other projects.